# Add Phonegap plugin without CLI

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to install an in-app-browser plugin on Phonegap and I need a little help

I don't have access to the PATH to be able to add Phonegap CLI to the PATH which means I cannot do this the usual way.

Can anyone suggest how I might be able to do this manually?

I should be using the latest Phonegap and am using the latest version of the desktop app

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it manually? 
A detailed description on how to do that can be found here: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin#manually.

It's about another plugin, but the principle should be the same.